# Add an additional condition within a function

Tags: r, function

I would like to add an additional condition to this function "wd".

It computes a deficit from the column "WB" which stands for water balance. Any deficit (when the WB is negative) is reported in the column "deficit" and accumulates over time. The record is reset to 0 when WB is positive.

I need to add an additional condition along with **if (df[[ varname_wbal ]][idx]<0)**: which could allow the deficit to be reset to 0 when the water balance "WB" is during the wettest month of the year.

The other characteristics of the code that initially follow "if (df[[ varname_wbal ]][idx]<0)" should remain the same.

I've tried to add to write the second condition like : "&& df$is_wettest_month[idx] == TRUE" and also "|| df$is_wettest_month[idx] == TRUE"

But it's not working; it does not provide the expected output. The tracking and recording of deficit event 'iinst' are not working properly, as well as the recording of the duration of deficit events 'dday'. Plus, it does not reset to 0 the deficit when the WB is during the wettest month.

Here is the function:

```
wd <- function(df, varname_wbal, varname_date, thresh_terminate = 0.0, thresh_drop = 0.9){
  
  
  if (thresh_terminate > thresh_drop){
    warning("Aborting. thresh_terminate must be smaller or equal thresh_drop. Setting it equal.")
    thresh_terminate <- thresh_drop
  }
  
  inst <- tibble()
  idx <- 0
  iinst <- 1
  
  df <- df |>
    ungroup() |>
    mutate(iinst = NA, dday = NA, deficit = 0)
  
  # search all dates
  while (idx <= (nrow(df)-1)){
    idx <- idx + 1
    
    # if the water balance (deficit = prec - et) is negative, start accumulating deficit
    # cumulative negative water balances (deficits)
    if (df[[ varname_wbal ]][idx]<0 ){
      
      dday <- 0
      deficit <- 0
      max_deficit <- 0
      iidx <- idx
      done_finding_dropday <- FALSE
      
      # continue accumulating deficit as long as the deficit has not fallen below (thresh_terminate) times the maximum deficit attained in this event
      while (iidx <= (nrow(df)-1) && (deficit - df[[ varname_wbal ]][iidx] > thresh_terminate * max_deficit)){
        dday <- dday + 1
        deficit <- deficit - df[[ varname_wbal ]][iidx]
        
        # record the maximum deficit attained in this event
        if (deficit > max_deficit){
          max_deficit <- deficit
          done_finding_dropday <- FALSE
        }
        
        # record the day when deficit falls below (thresh_drop) times the current maximum deficit
        if (deficit < (max_deficit * thresh_drop) && !done_finding_dropday){
          iidx_drop <- iidx
          done_finding_dropday <- TRUE
        }
        
        # once, deficit has fallen below threshold, all subsequent dates are dropped (dday set to NA)
        if (done_finding_dropday){
          df$iinst[iidx] <- NA
          df$dday[iidx]  <- NA
        } else {
          df$iinst[iidx] <- iinst
          df$dday[iidx]  <- dday
          iidx_drop <- iidx
        }
        
        # # (even before "drop-day" is found), drop data of days after rain, i.e., where current CWD is below the maximum (previously) attained in the same event
        # if (deficit < max_deficit){
        #   df$iinst[iidx] <- NA
        #   df$dday[iidx]  <- NA
        #   df$deficit[iidx] <- NA
        # } else {
        #   df$iinst[iidx] <- iinst
        #   df$dday[iidx]  <- dday
        #   df$deficit[iidx] <- deficit
        # }
        
        df$deficit[iidx] <- deficit
        
        iidx <- iidx + 1
        
      }
      
      # record instance
      this_inst <- tibble( idx_start = idx, len = iidx_drop-idx, iinst = iinst, date_start=df[[varname_date]][idx], date_end = df[[varname_date]][iidx_drop-1], deficit = max_deficit )
      inst <- inst |> bind_rows(this_inst)
      
      # update
      iinst <- iinst + 1
      dday <- 0
      idx <- iidx
    }
    
  }
  return( list(inst=inst, df=df))
}
```

You can find a sample of my daily data in for one grid cell over 73 year as an Rdata file (I cannot just copy paste because to check the results of the deficit you need several months):

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MYcNJnf3NVsaDM2Hq7gmnTVvaQYuBEaV/view?usp=share_link

Answer (score 1):

Without reading your code and trying to patch it up helpdesk-style, here is an interpretation of what you describe and a fast implementation, which might help you reimplement your own code. I've used `data.table` to illustrate, without piping and with annotations for clarity, which you can treat as pseudocode if you like.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df_grid)
```

**Interpretation 1**: *"accumulate runs of consecutive daily negative water balance that occur outside of the wettest month; zero everywhere else"*

```
# flag whether a value of WB counts for accumulation
df_grid[, accum_flag := (WB<=0 & !is_wettest_month)]

# flag whether the accumulation resets on this day
df_grid[, reset_flag := accum_flag != shift(accum_flag)][1, reset_flag := TRUE]

# group the data into runs
df_grid[, runID := cumsum(reset_flag)]

# accumulate within group
df_grid[, deficit := fifelse(accum_flag, cumsum(WB), 0), by=(runID)]

# remove the temporary columns if you wish
# df_grid[, c("accum_flag", "reset_flag", "runID") := NULL]
```

**Interpretation 2**: *"accumulate runs of consecutive daily negative water balance (including those that start in the wettest month), then overwrite the cumulative deficit with zero if within the wettest month; zero everywhere else"*

```
# As above but move the condition on wettest month from line 1 to line 4
df_grid[, accum_flag := WB<=0]
df_grid[, reset_flag := accum_flag != shift(accum_flag)][1, reset_flag := TRUE]
df_grid[, runID := cumsum(reset_flag)]
df_grid[, deficit := fifelse(accum_flag & !is_wettest_month, cumsum(WB), 0), by=(runID)]
# df_grid[, c("accum_flag", "reset_flag", "runID") := NULL]
```

**Output snippet** Note the difference according to whether the consecutive negative values of `WB` beginning 1952-07-29 are accumulated in `deficit`.

```
         time         WB is_wettest_month   deficit1  deficit2
       <Date>      <num>           <lgcl>      <num>     <num>
1: 1952-07-28  0.1070676             TRUE  0.0000000   0.00000
2: 1952-07-29 -3.5381990             TRUE  0.0000000   0.00000
3: 1952-07-30 -4.6770461             TRUE  0.0000000   0.00000
4: 1952-07-31 -4.7475482             TRUE  0.0000000   0.00000
5: 1952-08-01 -0.9419696            FALSE -0.9419696 -13.90476
6: 1952-08-02 -3.4563704            FALSE -4.3983400 -17.36113
7: 1952-08-03  0.9844645            FALSE  0.0000000   0.00000
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative but I need to stick to this code and its options otherwise I would have also done something else.

Comment: Not at all. Thanks for trying to help. I really appreciate.